# Is the a proper way to build a sitemap

Tags: sitemap

I am building a sitemap in which one is master and other are child

My master site map pattern is

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<script type="text/javascript" src="chrome-extension://adleiklellkmjhmnnoccodmonjdmbhhi/js/ei.js" id="m4rk-event-interceptor"/>
<div id="m4rk-extension-state" data-enabled="false" snapshot-enabled="false"/>
<test/>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.enggheads.com/#!team</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-06-19T17:27:46+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>http://www.enggheads.com/#!contactus</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-06-19T17:27:46+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
</url>
<sitemap>
     <loc>http://www.enggheads.com/sitemap1.xml</loc>
     <lastmod>2015-12-03</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
    <loc>http://www.enggheads.com/sitemap1.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-12-03</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
</urlset>
```

Is its a proper site map or there is something wrong in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a proper way to build a sitemap, and it is detailed here: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

What you should use in this case is a Sitemap Index that points to your other sitemaps, like this: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index

For example:

The following example shows a sitemap index that lists two sitemaps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap1.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2015-10-01T12:22:14+00:00</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap2.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2013-02-11</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   </sitemapindex>
```